# General conversion from three value logic down to two value logic

Tags: sql

I have a system using [OGC Filter Encoding](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-026r2/09-026r2.html), a generic filtering language that is similar to SQL, that is used to query a variety of backends.

When the backend happens to be a relational datatase, it's efficient to convert the filter down in SQL and let it run inside the database.

There is however a problem, OGC Filter encoding has a two-valued logic, while databases have three-valued logic, causing some filters to return a different result than if they were evaluated in memory.

I currently have a translation system that does the "obvious" thing, that is, visiting the filter definition tree and adding null checks to comparisons just in case there are negations in the upper levels of the filter, e.g. turning `not(a = 1)` into `not(a = 1 and a is not null)`.

I was wondering if anyone has figured more general translation mechanisms to force a SQL statement down into a two-valued logic behavior?

Solution should be database independent, I am targeting a variety of them (Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, db2, h2, SQLite and more).

Comment: "just in case there are negations in the upper levels of the filter" -> the result is not the same if you have "not(a = 1)". I'll clarify the example.

Comment: What about using `coalesce(a, -1) = 1` (the `-1` can be any value that is different from the constant on the right side)  - that should work on any DBMS.